# Pull comments from one page/post into another page/post?

Tags: plugins, comments, templates, page-template

I am creating a facebook app via wordpress but some how need to pull the comments off my homepage and insert them onto another page, essentially what I am trying to do is duplicate the homepage with a different url/page name. I have mananged to do so easily but I need the comments as well.

Thanks a tonne to anyone who can help in advance!

Comment: There is a bit more to this question than you have given, I believe. Are you wanting to have the ability to comment on both pages, and they both always have shared comments? What is the purpose of having the information in 2 places at once?

Comment: @EricHolmes Yes that is what I want. The reason for this is I need to have a popup on approved comment submission, the only way I have managed to get this to work is to have a redirect when a comment is submitted, then on that new page a timed lightbox popup. For that reason I want them re-directed to a page that looks the same as the homepage, so when they close the popup they can read their comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's the case you are going about it the wrong way. You should use [WP_Ajax_Response](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Ajax_Response) to send the comment, or just redirect the the same page. Duplicate content is not what WP is intended for.

Comment: Sorry im a bit of a newbie when it comes to this, could you maybe give me a bit more of an idea of what you would do?

Comment: Sure thing. What is the goal of this "approved comment submission" popup. Does Wordpress not automatically give you a message confirming the comment is put up?

Comment: Its to have a custom HTML lightbox with social sharing options and a thank you page. I think I have figured out a work around, what I have done is used the "lightbox pop" plugin which pops up a lightbox based on a number of options. I have set it to popup on a 2nd page load, so when someone submits it pops up.

Comment: I recommend using a Wordpress Plugin for social media sharing.

Comment: The issue is we need a custom design for the popup...I was just hoping to redirect to a new page with it.

Comment: If that is the case, pass back either a $_GET or $_POST variable like 'sent=true' or something, and redirect to the same page. If your page receives that $_GET variable, you can make it display the popup, otherwise don't display it. This way you can use the same page without all those complications.